# Makefile in C: all vs target -std=c1x error

Tags: c, makefile

I am working on a C homework assignment and I came across a simple yet specific error when creating my Makefile.

My initial Makefile was simple:

```
all: numbers.o
    gcc -Wall -pedantic -std=c1x numbers.c -o numbers
clean: 
    rm *.o
```

For whatever reason, despite the C program compiling correctly in the terminal, I repeatedly get the following error:

```
gcc: error: -std=c1x: No such file or directory 
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'all' failed
```

Comment: For sure it has nothing to do with target name. It looks like `gcc` did not treat the switch as a switch, but rather as a file name. Have you copied this command from somewhere? It happens that the `-` is not a simple dash but some dashy-looking Unicode character, most notably converted in word processors.

Comment: I asked a similar question about makefiles. Have look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1095317/create-executable-and-shared-library-with-one-makefile), maybe it will help you.

Comment: @raspy the dash must've been it, i copied it from a pdf file and when i rewrote it later after deleting it that must've been the fix. sorry for being naive about this

Answer (score -1):

The problem was actually because I had copied the gcc line from a pdf file. Thanks to the [comment by raspy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65141223/makefile-in-c-all-vs-target-std-c1x-error-self-answered#comment115164564_65141223):

> For sure it has nothing to do with target name. It looks like `gcc` did not treat the switch as a switch, but rather as a file name. Have you copied this command from somewhere? It happens that the `-` is not a simple dash but some dashy-looking Unicode character, most notably converted in word processors.

Comment: This is already covered in the question, which goes on to remark that changing the target name back did not cause the problem to return.  It follows that the target name is *not* the source of the problem, as I'm sure anyone with `make` expertise would tell you without performing the experiment.